# How to run the command lein run automatically after save?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

In a Leiningen project, I want to be able to run lein run each time I save a file in my project. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The best way is using the 
[lein test-refresh plugin](https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh).

This will monitor the file system, and re-run your unit tests upon each file save.  Simply make a unit test that calls `(myproj.core/-main)` or similar, and on each file save your program will re-run.

An even better way is to write a unit test that runs one or more functions (possibly including `-main`), and compares the actual output to the expected output.

Don't forget to look at the `:test-refresh/focus` metadata, which will allow you to select specific tests to run, temporarily ignoring others.

I use both features extensively in my lib [Tupelo Clojure](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo), which has over 3500 unit tests.  As an example, please see [the Clojure Template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template):

```
~/demo > git clone git@github.com:io-tupelo/clj-template.git
Cloning into 'clj-template'...
~/demo > 
~/demo > cd clj-template
~/demo/clj-template > lein test

lein test _bootstrap

-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 13
-------------------------------

lein test tst.demo.core

Ran 3 tests containing 8 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
~/demo/clj-template >
```

and the code:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.string :as ts])
  (:import [demo Calc]))

(dotest
  (is= 5 (+ 2 3))
  (isnt= 9 (+ 2 3))
  (throws? (/ 1 0)) ; verify that an illegal operation throws an exception

  (is= 3 (add2 1 2))
  (throws? (add2 1 "two"))) ; Prismatic Schema will throw since "two" is not a number
```

If you use `tupelo.test` like the above, you can just substitute `(dotest-focus ...)` instead of `dotest` and ***only*** that particular test(s) will run.

Another example is [the JUXT/bidi demo](https://github.com/io-tupelo-demo/bidi).

Enjoy!

---

### Update

If you want to investigate an alternate Leiningen test runner, please see [the Koacha lib](https://github.com/lambdaisland/kaocha).

Comment: That didn't work. After putting -main in a test and starting lein test-refresh, -main runs but making a change under the src directory doesn't re-run main.

Comment: Hmmmm, I don't know what to tell you.  I have used this workflow for years.  Changes to files under either the `src` or `test` dirs will cause a re-compile & re-test.

Comment: Please try the template project above - that should work for you.

Comment: Could be because I'm using run-jetty to run a server and am also connected to mongo db using monger?

Comment: Not really sure.  The above demo project doesn't even start up a web server.  Perhaps get that to work first?

Comment: Thanks @Alan Thomson. It works now, however, is there a way to use test runners like eftest with test-refresh?